# How to get the totals of each column MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I have an SQL query that get the number of jobs, gross weight etc for different companies.

The result in MySQL Workbench looks like this:
[image]

I would like to add another row at the bottom that calculates the total of each column i.e the total of the jobs column would be 267. How do I add an extra row for the totals?

SQL query:

```
select
            c.Name,
            COUNT(distinct jn.ID) as Jobs,
            SUM(jn.ActualWeight) as GrossWt,
            SUM(jpc.AdvisedQty) AS Units_In,
            SUM(jpd.AdvisedQty) AS Units_Out
            FROM customer c
        LEFT JOIN job_new jn ON jn.JobOwnerID = c.ID
        LEFT JOIN job_pieces jp ON jp.JobID = jn.ID
        LEFT JOIN job_pieces jpc ON jpc.JobID = jn.ID AND jn.CollectMemberID = jn.JobOwnerID
        LEFT JOIN job_pieces jpd ON jpd.JobID = jn.ID AND jn.DeliverMemberID = jn.JobOwnerID
   WHERE jn.IsActive = 1 GROUP BY jn.JobOwnerID
```

Comment: Try `GROUP BY c.Name` instead.

Comment: `GROUP BY jn.JobOwnerID WITH ROLLUP`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for the `GROUP BY` modifier [`WITH ROLLUP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-modifiers.html):

```
select c.Name,
       COUNT(distinct jn.ID) as Jobs,
       SUM(jn.ActualWeight) as GrossWt,
       SUM(jpc.AdvisedQty) AS Units_In,
       SUM(jpd.AdvisedQty) AS Units_Out
FROM customer c LEFT JOIN
     job_new jn
     ON jn.JobOwnerID = c.ID LEFT JOIN
     job_pieces jp
     ON jp.JobID = jn.ID LEFT JOIN 
     job_pieces jpc
     ON jpc.JobID = jn.ID AND jn.CollectMemberID = jn.JobOwnerID LEFT JOIN
     job_pieces jpd
     ON jpd.JobID = jn.ID AND jn.DeliverMemberID = jn.JobOwnerID
WHERE jn.IsActive = 1
GROUP BY c.Name WITH ROLLUP;
```

Note:  I also changed the `GROUP BY` key for two reasons.  First, it really should match the column used in the `SELECT`.  Second, you were using a value from a `LEFT JOIN`ed table, so the value could be `NULL`.  That is usually undesirable.

Comment: That's a very cool aggregate function, wasn't familiar with that.. +1

Comment: thanks it worked but for the name column it just copied the last name. Is there a way to make this row blank?

Comment: @user123456789 . . . In the aggregation row, `c.Name` should be `NULL`.  However, this only happens when the `GROUP BY` and column names are the same.  Don't put columns in the `SELECT` that are not aggregated and not in the `GROUP BY`.

Comment: ok thanks. But what if other columns that just contain text are added later. How would I also make that column blank in the aggregation row?

Comment: @user123456789 . . . Columns in the `select` should also be in the `group by` (if they are not aggregated).  This is not just a rule, it is actually pretty much what the ANSI standard is as well.